# jQuery event on initially hidden popup

Tags: jquery, events

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.close_popup', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Here, `.close_popup` is on a `div` which is hidden on page load, and is made visible on a popup (kind of modal dialog box) on clicking a button.

For some reason, I'm not getting the alert fired. Any tips here?

Thanks for your time.
Best.

**EDIT**

The class `.close_popup` is dynamically created once the popup loads, with a close button.

Comment: Is the element having .close-popup class hidden when you click it? You can't interact with a hidden element. If that's not what you mean, give us a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: is button having .close_popup class??

Comment: I faced a similar problem and found solution , here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380795/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-previously-hidden-div

Answer (score 0):

Is the script inside a document.ready tag?

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).click(function() {
      alert("clicked");
   });
});
```

Comment: I thought about that too, although, [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) proves us wrong. "The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready."

Comment: Then have you ran it with firebug or the javascript console built into chrome/IE (press F12). Usually shows most errors.

Comment: I'm not the question owner and I do not have the code.  I simply thought about that solution and by doing further reading I found that.  I thought it could be useful. :)

Comment: @MaximeMorin which solution you are speaking about here, please.

Comment: I was speaking of the above solution posted by @ErmSo.  That adding a $(document).ready() wrapper would fix your problem, but the documentation proved me wrong.  I do not have any other solutions.  Maybe if you add a demo or more code (HTML, js, css), it could feed our brains. :)

Answer (score 0):

theres no specific reason in this example why you would need to do jQuery(document).on('click', '.close_popup', function(){}); you should be able to get away with jQuery('.close_popup').on('click', function(){});  This is presuming that the .close_popup is your button element, that should also sort out your other question that links to this one.