# Jquery click event not firing on previously hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am loading a 'password-reset-success-message' div into a 'password-reset' div dynamically as shown in the below snippet.**The 'password-reset-success-message' div is hidden on page  load** and is overwritten to the 'password-reset' div as shown below.

```
    $("#password-reset").html($("#password-reset-success-message").html());
```

Now the  'password-reset-success-message' div has a 'btnPasswordResetOK' button which will close the password reset modal dialog.But this click() event is not getting binded. I am not getting the alert message. I am doing all of this wrapped inside the document ready.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){  

       $("#btnPasswordResetOK").click(function() {

         alert();
       });

    });
```

Note: [This question is almost similar to my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048509/jquery-event-on-initially-hidden-popup).but there are not answers for it.

**UPDATE :**  I binded after updating the html with the hidden div and it works ! , code snippet below

```
      $("#password-reset").html($("#password-reset-success-message").html());

       $("#btnPasswordResetOK").click(function() {

            alert();
       });
```

Comment: Need to see your HTML please.

Comment: is the #btnPasswordResetOK part of the #password-reset-success-message html? What happens if you bind the button after you have updated the html or if you change the click to live?

Comment: @kleinkie yes #btnPasswordResetOK button is inside the hidden div , I will try binding the button after the html update and revert back to you.

Comment: I think live might actually do the trick (Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.) http://api.jquery.com/live/ as opposed to click (Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.) http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @kleinkie binded the button event after updating and it works ! thank you.

Comment: cool - just check that all scenarios of your flow work (html is replaced with something else containing a different button) etc.

Comment: @TitoCheriachan yes binding after creation also works too.. but using delegation is easier since you don't have to have your click binding inside another function.

Comment: @wirey I will try the delegation too , as it will decouple the code from the outer function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delegate it to the parent element you are adding the html to

if using jQuery 1.7+ with .on()

```
$("#password-reset").on('click','#btnPasswordResetOK',function(){

})
```

with delegate

```
$("#password-reset").delegate('#btnPasswordResetOK','click',function(){

})
```

From jQuery docs on which method to use

> $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
>
> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
>
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

By delegating, you bind the event handler to a static parent element that doesn't change and exists at the time of binding.  You specify the element and the events you want to listen to, and when the event bubbles up it will get handled by the static parent element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Your content is not there on the page when ready event is triggered. You generate the elements and content dynamically so you must use live/on event handler.