# jquery: click event handler doesn't fire previously hidden elements

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function (e) {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

It works for all elements on the current page, however, when I click an element, which renders a div element that was hidden before, it will not let me click it.

How can I catch the click event on the previously hidden element that is now present?

Comment: Can you sketch a quick jsfiddle showing this?

Comment: what do you mean by _hidden_?

Answer (score 1):

The click event is registered for already loaded items. Any element added dynamically don't seems having that event registered and hence the click event won't work. At least, I run into this issue before. But the following will fix it.

```
 $(".hiddenFieldIdentifier").on("click",function(){
 {
       //alert('Yes it worked!');
 });
```

Please note the place holder: hiddenFieldIdentifier

Look the "on" JQuery API documentation

Edited:
 It looks like this is similar to: [Jquery click event not firing on previously hidden div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380795/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-previously-hidden-div?rq=1)

Adding this after the user added a link to their code:
It works as is but do you have any reason to register the click even for ANY element click?
Here is what I got:[image]
So as you can see, it worked. But it will be nice to register the click event only for the intended elements. Right now, a click on anywhere is going to fire the event. And I am guessing the "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" flag might be checked. Try on a new tab or restart the browser to re-enable that and do your test.
Again your code will keep showing that dialog unless you click on this flag which will prevent the dialog from showing up again.

Hope it helps
Happy coding!

Comment: what if I don't know the name of the hidden element ahead of time?

Comment: If you don't have a class or id applied to it to easily identify the element, the element can be still identified from where its positioned at (from a known element which will serve you as a parent or sibling to start your navigation to it). Can you please post your code so i can take a look?

Comment: im trying to run a simple 'click' on handler code at this page http://vancouver.craigslist.ca/van/acc/4581984031.html (copy paste to console), and click the 'reply' button, notice you can't click anything inside the box

Comment: There isn't any button called or labeled "reply". I also looked at the source code in case there was any hidden but nope. Are you sure this is the page you are working on or you are advertising something here? If you are not, please do post the source code and clearly specify what kind of behavior you want to see. And what do you mean by "(copy paste to console)"?

Comment: @user3818345 try this one http://vancouver.craigslist.ca/rds/acc/4582466498.html (you can copy my code and run it on that page by opening up a console), using Chrome

Comment: It works for me. Please see my updated answer above (with the screen shot included).

Comment: of course it works on anywhere but when you click on teh reply button and click the email, it won't fire. it will fire when you click on reply but not on the box that appears below it

Comment: It looks like you are changing your question and besides, the source code looks suspicious from security point of view too. If you really are seeking a solution, DO POST JUST THE SOURCE CODE and not a link. I was trying to help but ...

Comment: there's no way im going to accept this answer now. you should just delete it so I can close this question.

Comment: Why is that you don't want to POST THE SOURCE CODE YOU HAVE here instead of the link?

Comment: That is just a JS script. How about the HTML SOURCE CODE? Can you do that please. Just the html code plus clearly state which element you want to click and what exactly you want to happen?